# Save cell arrays in one CSV - Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, cell

I have a script which generates a 2 cell array (x and y coordinates). How can I merge them (two columns), save them in one CSV file so I can read them later in Excel?

Comment: Where is your problem implementing this? Do you know how to write a single cell to a csv? Using `cat` you can concatenate both cell arrays.

Comment: and then you can use `csvwrite` to write the csv file

Comment: I use the horzcat(x,y) to merge them but how can it? as the csvwrite  does not work

Comment: you need to provide more info on why it is not working. What does the error say? Are the dimensions of your x and y the same?

Comment: `newarray=cat(1,myarray(:,1),myarray(:,2));` something like this is what you are looking for. However can't you write a nxm array to excel? Never tried it, but I am pretty sure it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below some simplified code which has two solutions that  might help you

```
x = 1:10;
y = 11:20;
x = num2cell(x);
y = num2cell(y);

x2 = cell2mat(x);
y2 = cell2mat(y);

newmat = [x2;y2]';
csvwrite('output.csv',newmat)

fid = fopen ('output2.csv','w');
for i = 1:length(x)
    fprintf (fid,'%f, %f\n',x{i},y{i});
end
fclose (fid);
```

related to what GameOfThrows mentions this only works if x and y have the same length

Note the first solutions converts the cell to an arra which might not always give the result as shown in the example. The second is a more general one with a formatted output...